# Rounding off an arraylist to an integer array

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, rounding

I've been trying with this problem but couldn't wrap my head around it..
"Create a java method int [] roundoff (ArrayList input) that returns a new integer array containing all the input doubles correctly rounded off to integers."

This is where I got so far:

package javaProblem;

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class TowMethods {
    public static int[] roundOff(ArrayList<Double> input) {

        int [] iL=new int[input.size()];
        for (double i:iL) {
            //input.get(i);
            int n=(int) Math.round(i) ;
            iL[n]=n;
        }
        System.out.print(Arrays.toString(iL));
        return (iL);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Double> input1 = new ArrayList<Double>();
        input1.add(2.3);
        input1.add(1.3);
        input1.add(3.35);
       /* for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            double num = keyboard.nextDouble();
            input.add(num);
        }*/
        int[] iList = roundOff(input1);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(iList));

    }
}
```

Comment: `double i : iL` iL is the int array you just created, don't you want `input`?

Comment: OK. And what is your question?

Comment: "Create a java method int [] roundoff (ArrayList input) that returns a new integer array containing all the input doubles correctly rounded off to integers."

Comment: Let me add emphasis to what JB Nizet said: "what is **your** question?*, in other words what *you* want to ask us about? For now you just quoted task given to you, but that doesn't include description of things which you have problem with.

Comment: Use [edit] option to clarify your question.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < input.size(); i++) {
    iL[i] = (int)(Math.round(input.get(i)));
}
```

Instead of your loop in roundOff method

Answer (score 1):

Please try to use meaningful names when you name your variables. Also inside the *roundOff* method instead of the `foreach` loop use a classic `for` loop and don't iterate through the freshly created integer array but over the ArrayList which you take as a parameter.

Here is the possible solution:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TowMethods {

    public static int[] roundOff(ArrayList<Double> inputs) {

        int [] integers=new int[inputs.size()];
        for (int i=0; i < inputs.size(); i++) {

            integers[i] = (int) Math.round(inputs.get(i));

        }

        return integers;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       // Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Double> inputs = new ArrayList<Double>();

        inputs.add(2.3);
        inputs.add(1.3);
        inputs.add(3.35);

        /*
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            double num = keyboard.nextDouble();
            inputs.add(num);
        }
        */
        int[] iList = roundOff(inputs);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(iList));

    }
}
```

If you want to take the user input just uncomment the commented lines in the `main` method.

Answer (score 0):

Use `Math.rint()` which properly rounds to the next int value.

```
        double [] dbls = {2.4, 8.8, 22.23, 97.6};
        int[] ints = new int[dbls.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < dbls.length; i++) {
            ints[i] = (int)Math.rint(dbls[i]);
        }

        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(dbls));
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(ints));
```

Prints

> [2.4, 8.8, 22.23, 97.6] 
>   [2, 9, 22, 98]